# Cheap string storage for a document

Tags: solr

I want to add tags to an existing document. The `tags` field is stored  but not indexed, but I want to see the **latest value** of `tags` without the overhead of a (soft) commit. For example `q=christmas&fl=text,tags` will return latest tags before they are commited.

I know Solr 4.0 has partial document updates, but it still has to reindex the document before that change is visible.

Is there a way to get the latest value without doing costly reindexes; such as with NRT?

---

I prefer the results come with the old query handlers.

I dont mind upto a few seconds of delay, in case of NRT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using the [ExternalFileField](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-ALPHA/org/apache/solr/schema/ExternalFileField.html) in Solr. This is probably the only way to get storage of a value that is not stored directly in the index. However, every time the file is updated it must be reloaded, so that could be a potential performance concern - See [ExternalFileField Best Practices from the Solr Mailing List](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/ExternalFileField-best-practices-td1379672.html).

Also, here is a good walk through for how to use [ExternalFileField in Solr](http://www.findwise.com/blog/externalfilefield-in-solr/), if you decide to do so.

**Update:**

I would recommend the use of the [RealTime Get](http://java.dzone.com/articles/solr-40-realtime-get) via `/get` that comes with Solr 4.0. This provides the exact functionality that you are looking for. You can then combine this with document updates to not need to update the entire document each time.

**Update2: RealTimeGetComponent**

So I looked at the handlers source code and there is a [RealTimeGetComponent](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_0_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/handler/component/RealTimeGetComponent.html). I enabled it on the default `/select` handler as follows. The main item is setting the `&get=true` parameter and making it a last-component.

```
<!-- RealTimeGet Component-->
<searchComponent name="realtimeGet" class="solr.RealTimeGetComponent"/>

<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
   <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
     <int name="rows">10</int>
     <str name="df">text</str>
     <bool name="get">true</bool>
   </lst>
   <arr name="last-components">
     <str>realtimeGet</str>
   </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

The query - `/select?q=id%3Amydoc2&wt=xml&id=mydoc2`  will produce the following output:

```
    <response>
       <lst name="responseHeader">
         <int name="status">0</int>
         <int name="QTime">2</int>
         <lst name="params">
           <str name="id">mydoc2</str>
           <str name="wt">xml</str>
           <str name="q">id:mydoc2</str>
         </lst>
      </lst>
      <result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
        <doc>
          <str name="id">mydoc2</str>
          <arr name="title">
            <str>realtime-get updated3</str>
          </arr>
          <long name="_version_">1419891443321798656</long>
        </doc>
      </result>
      <doc name="doc">
        <str name="id">mydoc2</str>
        <arr name="title">
          <str>realtime-get updated - new</str>
        </arr>
        <long name="_version_">1419892263820984320</long>
      </doc>
    </response>
```

So in this example it is querying for the item with `id=mydoc2` and then getting the latest version of the item `id=mydoc2` and showing the difference in `_version_` and `title` values.

However, in order to get this you will need to pass the id or ids of the documents to get the updated versions for. It does not appear that this component is coded to be able to pull the updated documents for the query being executed in the requestHandler where it is being used. This would be a nice future feature.

Comment: I did not mean that the field will be outside the index. It is a field in the document itself. I edited that phrase.

Comment: Is there a way to get RealTimeGet values in regular solr request handlers? I quote "realtime get component that can be inserted into any request handler, including the standard request handler". Is this implemented/proposed? I want to avoid 2 calls to Solr